# How can I get the seed of a Dedicated Minecraft Bedrock Server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have my own Minecraft Bedrock Server, and I want to get the seed of it. How can I do this?

The /seed command does not exist on the client or the server, even with operator permissions.

Comment: `/seed` isn't an option on Bedrock Edition; as a workaround, assuming you have access to the world file, look into the world options; according to [gamepedia,](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Seed_(level_generation)) it should be there. (note this isn't a full answer as i don't know if this is correct)

Comment: `look into the world options` I'm using a dedicated server, there are no world options for dedicated servers

Comment: You have the world file, yes? Can you copy that over to singleplayer then open the world options there, perhaps using Win10 Edition?

Comment: @Corsaka I don't think that copying a 10GB world over [Remote Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) from the server to my desktop/client is a good idea.

Comment: Then I'm afraid, to the best of my knowledge, it's impossible.

Answer (score 4):

While you're in the world, you can open Settings, click Game, and scroll down until you see the Seed.

Comment: What if I don't have access to the world file or can't check the world options?

Answer (score 4):

I couldnt find the solution, but figured it must be in the game file somewhere.

So, Open the games data folder with a Hex Editor. As a recommendation, I use VSCode Hex Editor.
\worlds\HappyLifeWorld\level.dat

In this file you will see "RandomSeed" around value 310. The Seed is the next 10 bytes after the text, ignoring the 00 afterwards. The seed you need to enter is the int64 value on the right of the screenshot.
[image]

BTW, the seed on that screenshot is really cool. You spawn in a desert with a pillager tower about 50 blocks in front of you, a village 20 blocks away from it and a desert temple on a nearby hill.